# ORA-609 TNS-12638 Credential retrieval failed

Tags: oracle, credentials

I'm having this error every second

> **alert.log**
>
> ```
> 08/03/2018 11:32:07 a.m. - opiodr aborting process unknown ospid (3888) as a result of ORA-609
>
> 08/03/2018 11:32:17 a.m. - opiodr aborting process unknown ospid (18896) as a result of ORA-609
> ```
>
> **sqlnet.log**
>
> ```
> Fatal NI connect error 12638, connecting to:
>  (LOCAL=NO)
>
>   VERSION INFORMATION:
>   TNS for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.4.0 - Production
>   Oracle Bequeath NT Protocol Adapter for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.4.0 - Production
>   Windows NT TCP/IP NT Protocol Adapter for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.4.0 - Production
>   Time: 08-MAR-2018 11:33:49
>   Tracing not turned on.
>   Tns error struct:
>     ns main err code: 12638
>     TNS-12638: Credential retrieval failed
>     ns secondary err code: 0
>     nt main err code: 0
>     nt secondary err code: 0
>     nt OS err code: 0
> ```

Comment: You were all right and then you saw this error? Or Was this a mistake from the very beginning?
Something changed in setting up windows authentication?
When did you see this error?
For diagnostics we need files from the client computer `$ORACLE_HOME/network/admin/sqlnet.ora` `$ORACLE_HOME/network/admin/tnsnames.ora`

Comment: We managed to fix this by doing this:

Enable in this file:
C:\Oracle\Ora112\NETWORK\ADMIN\sqlnet.ora

TRACE_LEVEL_SERVER=16

16=Support

And then we were able to see the error in detail.

We changed this:
SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES= (NTS) for SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES= (NONE)